# Grid image values to 2D array

Tags: arrays, image, image-processing, grid, autoit

I have a grid like the image below which I want to put in an array in this format:

```
 ;x = wall(black cells and grey boxes), s= start (red circle), g = goal(blue circle), 0 = available path(everything else)
 $data[5][5] = [["x","x","x","x","x"], _
               ["x","s","0","x","x"], _
               ["x","x","0","x","x"], _
               ["x","x","0","g","x"], _
               ["x","x","x","x","x"]]
```

[image]

I thought I could use the colors but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **looks like you have the view with fixed angles**

   create function that converts screen position to grid position and back. It should be easy just `2x` linear interpolation. if the camera pan is not with cell based step then you need the corner point of grid lines and use that as a start point ...

   for example something like this (hope I measured the pixels correctly):

   [image: grid function]

   ```
   x = 236 + (+(u-uh)-(v-vh))*60;
   y = 133 + (-(u-uh)-(v-vh))*30;
   ```

   - `60,30`is the cell size in `x,y`
   - `(236,133)` is position of center of mid cell `(uh,vh)` in pixels
   - `uh,vh` are coordinates in your grid of center cell

   add the views pan offset to `(uv,hv)` or `(236,133)` now just compute the also the reverse transform from this `(u=?,v=?)`. Do not forget that the map is not rectangle! It is something like this:

   ```
       0000x0000,
       000xxx000,
       00xxxxx00,
       0xxxxxxx0,
       xxxxxxxxx,
       0xxxxxxx0,
       00xxxxx00,
       000xxx000,
       0000x0000,
   ```
2. **create a set of images of all objects that you can encounter**

   this can be done on the run, each time you do not found a match add cell to item list as new object type.
3. **loop through all grid cell locations and compare to object types**

   for pixel precise rendered images you can compare directly pixels **1:1** if that is not the case the you need to compare objects more robustly. But to make a valid algorithm we need to see all the types of object you can encounter usually you can compare:

   1. average,min and max colors, histograms,
   2. aspect ratio,...
   3. **FFT/DCT**
   4. center of mass position,density, and more

   do not forget to mask comparison to area of cell only to not include the neighboring cells on corners of bounding rectangle

**[Notes]**

Can not be more specific without further info

Comment: The reason why I want to create this 2D array is because I want to be able to use a path finding algorithm. I found a working one at http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/47161-artificial-intelligence-bot-path-finding/?page=1. The camera will never move and the image is always the same size

Comment: @phil652 Take a look at [Improving performance of click detection on a staggered column isometric grid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35917976/2521214) I think it might interests you I share my C++ isometric engine source there  it might get handy for you ...